# High action on higher fret on my steel acoustic guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar, maintenance, action

It's been 2 years since the last time I played guitar. I tried to play again this morning and something feels off. I felt sore on my wrist when trying to play barre chords for just a few strums. I don't know if it's just my hands not getting used to after 2 years of break.

I remember something about action and measured my guitar's action. And there is quite a gap between the action on its 1st fret and 15th fret. The action on the 1st fret is around 1 - 2 mm and 5-6 mm on the 15th fret. I'm not sure if this is normal or not. For comparison, the action on my electric guitar is pretty much the same across all fret (1-2 mm on the 1st fret and 2-3 mm on the last fret).

Should I adjust the truss rod? I never do this before so I'm worried if I broke my guitar because of it. Here are some pictures of my guitar's action for reference:

**1st Fret:**
[image: 1st Fret Action]

**15th Fret:**
[image: 15th Fret Action]

Answer (score 1):

Look down the neck and see how its shape is compared to the very straight strings. It probably needs a tweak of the truss rod, to bring fingerboard and neck more closely in line with each other. Compare with the other guitar and you'll get a better idea.

Comment: I agree with Tim's advice, but would simply recommend using small truss rod adjustments, like an eighth of a turn or so. And don't force it! If the adjuster becomes stiff, you may be a the end of the threads; continuing to force it may break it at that point. Lastly, allow some time for the guitar to settle before making another adjustment; I prefer overnight.

Comment: @Tim I looked at my friend's guitar. Its action is more or less the same (we both took a break at the same time and have the same model). I tried to look down the neck from the headstock and from the bridge but can't find any curve.

Comment: @KirkA I did a half of a turn after looking at my owner's manual. Alas, no change on the action height. Maybe I should bring it to the shop. It bothers me how tight it feels when turning the truss road. I thought I was going to break my guitar.

Comment: Bringing it to the shop is the right thing to do in my opinion. Ask the luthier to teach you some stuff while you are there.

Comment: Is it possible that the action is supposed to be in this height for my guitar's model? Considering my friend's guitar is also in this state. I couldn't really remember how high it was when I first bought it.

Comment: Perhaps they both need a little light relief. There is nothing much wrong with the neck if it looks pretty straight. You could try lowering the saddles or the bridge. There is no real need to have a high action on a well-made guitar. Unless you play slide. If the bridge is non-adjustable, take it to a luthier as b3ko suggests.